# Implement Queue using fixed size array

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I came across below interview question and I am working on it:

> Build a queue class with the enqueue and dequeue methods. The queue
>   can store an **UNLIMITED** number of elements but you are limited to
>   using arrays that can store up to 5 elements max..

Here is what I was able to come up with. Is this the right way to do it in the interview or is there any better way we should implement in the interview?

```
class Solution {  
  private final List<List<Integer>> array;

  public Solution() {
    this.array = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public void enqueue(int value) {
    if(array.isEmpty()) {
      List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
      arr.add(value);
      array.add(arr);
      return;
    }
    if(array.get(array.size() - 1).size() != 5) {
      array.get(array.size() - 1).add(value);   
      return;
    }
    List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    arr.add(value);
    array.add(arr);
    return;
  }

  public int dequeue() {
    if(array.isEmpty()) {
      return -1; 
    }
    for(List<Integer> l : array) {
      for(int i=0; i<l.size(); i++) {
        return l.remove(i); 
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Make it circular, by using a pointer to current head, also record the actual size, when overflow, replace & discard the oldest element.

Comment: I'm confused. If you can use an array of size only 5, you can't possibly store an unlimited number items, right? Or can you get rid of the older elements like @EricWang suggests?

Comment: Your solution uses an array of arbitrary length to hold arrays of length 5, so it doesn't solve the problem. To get arbitrary size, you need to implement something like a 5-ary tree where the leaves are the integers. Of course no computer can hold any data structure of UNLIMITED size because real computers can only address a finite amount of memory. In an interview you'd do well to explain that.

Comment: Or a linked list of 4-element nodes.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in comments, your solution doesn't really solve the problem because the outer array of 5-element arrays can have more than 5 elements.

Instead, you can implement the queue as a linked list of 4-integer nodes, using the 5th element for a reference to the next array. But there's no reason to assume the elements are integers. This turns out to be pretty simple.

```
public class SillyQueue<T> {
  private static final int MAX = 5;
  private Object [] head = new Object[MAX], tail = head;
  private int headPtr = 0, tailPtr = 0;

  void enqueue(T x) {
    if (tailPtr == MAX - 1) {
      Object [] a = new Object[MAX];
      tail[MAX - 1] = a;
      tail = a;
      tailPtr = 0;
    }
    tail[tailPtr++] = x;
  }

  T dequeue() {
    if (headPtr == MAX - 1) {
      head = (Object[]) head[MAX - 1];
      headPtr = 0;
    }
    return (T) head[headPtr++];
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution right now doesn't take care of memory after deque that won't be used ever again. A separate program to free up those memory areas would be needed to keep memory leak in check (just for the sake in an interview). Correct me if I missed something.

Comment: @UtkarshGupta No that's not a problem. Nodes bypassed by `head` no longer have any references, so the JVM's garbage collector will get them.  Same as popping the head not from a linked list.

Comment: Yes, you're right in the case of Java. But still, it needs to be handled for languages that don't come with the GC and expects the programmer to free the memory, i.e. c, c++, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer uses `ArrayList` instead of true arrays, and worse, uses an unlimited arraylist to put those arrays in. I think that the interviewers expected you to implement a singly-linked list of 5-element arrays:

```
/**
 * A singly-linked list node with an array; supports popping its 1st elements, 
 * and adding elements at the end, possibly by creating a new node
 */
public class ListNode {
    final int MAX = 5;
    private int contents[] = new int[MAX];
    private int size = 0; // valid elements

    private ListNode next = null;
    private ListNode(ListNode next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() { return size == 0; }

    public ListNode addLast(int value) {
        ListNode next = this;
        if (size == MAX) {
            next = new ListNode(this);
        }
        next.contents[next.size ++] = value;
        return next;
    }

    public int removeFirst() {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("empty queue");
        }
        int value = contents[0];
        size --;
        for (int i=1; i<size; i++) contents[i-1] = contents[i];
        return value;
    }
}

/**
 * A simple queue on top of nodes that keep arrays of elements
 */
public class ListArrayQueue {
    ListNode first = new ListNode();
    ListNode last = first;
    public void enqueue(int value) {
        last = last.addLast(value);
    }
    public int dequeue() {
        if (first.isEmpty() && first != last) {
            first = first.next;
        }
        return first.removeFirst();
    }
}
```

Performance-wise, this can be improved: you can avoid keeping the `size` in each `ListNode`, since only the 1st and last nodes can be non-full. You can also avoid the loop in `removeFirst`, but that would entail replacing `size` by `firstIndex` and `lastIndex`; which could again be moved into the `ListArrayQueue` to save space in each node.

If they has asked you to build an unlimited array out of 5-element array pieces, you would have had to implement something similar to a [b-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). Which, without handy references, would be quite hard to pull off during an interview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 1-D array and use Wrap-around indexing to implement the queue with the limitation that queue can contain maximum 5 elements.

For checking the condition of empty queue, maintain a variable that counts the number of elements present in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

`Is this the right way to do it in the interview…?`
Presenting uncommented code is never right, let alone in an interview.
In an interactive interview, it would be your task to find out whether you can/should use an *unlimited* number of *array**s***. 
If not, you have to negotiate a way to handle an `enqueue()` to a queue filled to capacity in addition to a `dequeue()` to an empty one. 
Fix the type of *items* the queue can hold. 
Agree upon the parameters of the `enqueue and dequeue methods`.

The task is to `Build a queue class`, `Solution` is a bad choice for a name - `array` for something to access the items is no better.
In a language providing arrays, I'd take `limited to using arrays` literally - if using something more, why not an implementation of `java.util.Queue`?
The *empty queue handling* is entirely redundant: in `enqueue()`, you could have used
`if (!array.isEmpty() && array.get(array.size() - 1).size() < 5)`; in `dequeue()` you can just drop it.
Instantiating `List<Integer>`s, *you know* there won't be more than five items at a time: tell the constructor.
`dequeue()` leaves empty `List<Integer>`s in `arrays`, giving rise to the current nested loop that desperately needs a comment.

(For the second part of the question, I second [Rajkamal Tomar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55740878).)

Answer (score 0):

### Trade Off - Organize Fixed Size Arrays

#### Manage arrays based on ArrayList

- enqueue - append new fixed size array - O(1)
- dequeue - remove first fixed size array - O(n)

#### Manage arrays based on LinkedList

- enqueue - append new fixed size array to linked list - O(1)
- dequeue - remove first fixed size array - O(1)
- cons - extra next pointer to setup linked list

```java
public class FixedArrayQueue<T> {
    private Node<T> head, tail;
    private int front, rear, size;
    private final int SIZE;

    public FixedArrayQueue(int n) {
        SIZE = n;
        head = tail = new Node<T>(SIZE);
        front = rear = size = 0;
    }

    public void enqueue(T t) {
        tail.array[rear++] = t;
        if (rear == SIZE) {
            rear = 0;
            append();
        }
        size++;
    }

    public T dequeue() {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new EmptyQueueException();
        }
        T ret = head.array[front++];
        if (front == SIZE) {
            front = 0;
            remove();
        }

        size--;
        return ret;
    }

    private void append() {
        tail.next = new Node<T>(SIZE);
        tail = tail.next;
    }

    private void remove() {
        head = head.next;
    }

    private boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    private int size() {
        return size;
    }
}

class Node<T> {
    T[] array;
    Node<T> next;

    public Node(int n) {
        array = (T[]) new Object[n];
    }
}
```